# Logging for C/C++ with full control over logging

Tags: c++, logging

What are recommendation on C++ logging library/framework with full control over it. I want to be able to have a full control over where logs are stored, what information to produce and show/hide without having compilation errors. I have tried log4cxx and log4cplus but they dont have complete control over logging.

Answer (score 2):

I use [GLog](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/) for some projects. It works quite well. It has many features that allow you to control different aspects of logging.

There is [Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html). However, as the site says, it is not officially part of Boost. It did conditionally pass review, but there are some heavy duty fixes suggested. It is a shame as I like to get as much as I can from Boost for consistency.

Comment: What do you mean by `it's pretty dead`? Looking [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log/develop) it was last updated 8 hrs ago.

Comment: When I was looking at the documentation a while back, all I saw was copyright dates from 2010. At that point, I dismissed it. That, and the structure of the library was already turning me off. However, since it is being updated, I will edit that out of my answer.

Comment: @JesseGood I would say its in an Alpha stage still,

Comment: I am tring to keey this project away from Boost. GLog is a good option.